# Where to store auth token (frontend) and how to put it in http headers of multiple endpoints?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, rest, django-rest-framework

> I wanted to write auth backend for both mobile and webapp, so I decided to go with the DRF (Django Rest Framework) token authentication.
>
> I pretty much figured out backend via DRF documentation but regarding frontend implementation it just says "*include token in the header of every http request to the API*."

---

So my question is

1. **When I retrieve token in AJAX call where should I store it so that upon browser refresh it doesn't disappear?**
   (Apparently I'm not using cookies, because phones have restriction on cookie uses )
2. **How to insert the auth token in the http headers of multiple API endpoints?**

With the help of Stackoverflow I figured out how to insert auth token in a single http header.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.something.com/random",
  type: 'get',
  headers: {
    token: "t&jdd9HJKHdss7hkjjkhdshgs",
  }
});
```

I was wondering If I have to write this piece of code for every endpoints or is there a way cover all the endpoints without being redundant?

Comment: Try storing the token in session storage:  `sessionStorage.setItem('token', value);` And retrieve it using: `sessionStorage.getItem('token');`

Comment: What about the localStorage? Wouldn't localStorage be more suitable for this?

Comment: If you want ti retain those value even after the browser/window is closed, you can use `localStorage`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three ways how to store a token in a browser:

1. **LocalStorage** - stores data with no expiration date, no access from a backend.
2. **SessionStorage** - stores data until browser/tab is open, no access from a backend.
3. **Cookie** - stores data, expiration time can be set individually, automatically sent with subsequent requests to the server.

More here: https://scotch.io/@PratyushB/local-storage-vs-session-storage-vs-cookie

So, the only **Cookie** would do it automatically for you, all the rest - you would need to provide manually.

You can choose from both **LocalStorage** and **SessionStorage**, but if you want your users to be logged in next time they open a page - I would choose a **LocalStorage**.

Then it needs to be added manually to every API request, but you can create a helper function to make it easier:

```
function apiRequest(type, url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    headers: {
      token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    }
  });
}

apiRequest("get","https://www.something.com/random").done(function(data) {
  console.log(data) 
})
```

More about localStorage here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You can use Local-storage and use interceptor for attaching the token in single place.
There is a similar question on stack overflow. [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780192/user-authentication-on-a-mobile-angularjs-app)